# Como fazer sequência Fibonacci através de matriz?

Tags: c, matemática, fibonnaci

Estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo em C que exibe uma sequência Fibonacci na tela, porém primeiramente construí uma planilha no Excel para entender o funcionamento desta sequência e percebi que ela se trata de uma matriz de 3 colunas, nas quais o valor de uma coluna, quando passado pra linha de baixo retorna para a coluna anterior. Como exemplo na célula C4 o valor é 3, e esse mesmo valor 3 vai futuramente pra célula B5. Haveria a possibilidade de criar essa sequência através de matriz? Como eu poderia fazer? Pois já tentei de tudo incluindo somar os elementos de colunas distintas e assim os exibir em sequência e não deu certo.[image: Tabela da sequência Fibonacci]

Comment: Perfeitamente possível. Conforme as normas deste site fazermos o programa para você. [Que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta)

Comment: O que está procurando chama-se Generalização Tensorial da Sequencia de Fibonacci.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem o que queria, mas segue um exemplo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 5
#define COLUNAS 3
#define COL1 0
#define COL2 1
#define COL3 2
void main(){
   int matriz[TAM][COLUNAS];
   int col1, col2,inc;
   col1=0;
   inc=0;
   while(inc<TAM){
       if(inc==0){
           col2=1;
           col1 = col2;
       }
       else{
           col1 = col2;
           col2=matriz[inc-1][COL3];
       }
       matriz[inc][COL1]=col1;
       matriz[inc][COL2]=col2;
       matriz[inc][COL3]= col1 + col2;
       inc+=1;
   }
   printf("Registrado %d elementos\n", inc);
   puts("Imprimindo a Matriz sequencia de Fibonacci\n\n");
   printf("ELEM 1\tELEM 2\tRESULT\n");
   for (inc = 0 ; inc <TAM ; inc++)
    printf("%6d\t%6d\t%6d\n",  matriz[inc][COL1], matriz[inc][COL2], matriz[inc][COL3]  );  
}
```

Comment: Exatamente era mais ou menos esse ideia que eu queria, vlw pela ajuda. Vou usar como base pra alterar algumas coisas nele, já quebrou um galho.